# Open/Closed principle and violation of encapsulation

Tags: java, open-closed-principle

Could you please check if the following code is correct or not? The fact is that I found something similar in propduction code and I have doubt if it matches Open/Closed principle.

```
public abstract class CustomClass {

    private ClassThatSetEnvironmentProperty sysProp = new ClassThatSetEnvironmentProperty("SYS_PROPETY", "SYS_PROPERTY_VALUE");

    // some code here

    void setSysProp(ClassThatSetEnvironmentProperty sysProp) {
        this.sysProp = sysProp;
    }
}
```

My understanding is the setter is defined for unit-tests possibilities only (to mock `ClassThatSetEnvironmentProperty`). But in this case the setter allows concrete inheritants to change defined state. From my perspective it violates encapsulation. More over I think that it is also violates open/closed prinicple. Frankly, some of my coleagues takes an opposite view. I really have not to much experience so it is hard for me to recognise it. Please share your opinion here. Thank you.

Comment: I would prefer constructor injection over setter injection.

Comment: You are right and I totally agree with you. But what about current case?

Comment: The definition of the Open/Closed principle states that one should be able to change the behaviour of a class without modifying its source code. In this case, I don't think it violates the principle at all. The source code stays the same but `sysProp` is changed.

Comment: Current case uses setter injection; I would use constructor.  You could make it immutable and not break encapsulation.

Comment: @christopher Ok, thank you. But my understanding is `ClassThatSetEnvironmentProperty` instantiation is defined in abstract class to defined a part of common state for inheritants. If the property can be changed would it be better to define it in each concrete class?

Comment: If each concrete class is independent, then yes.  Otherwise no.  You added it to your abstract class.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't directly relate to the Open Closed Principle, The Open Closed Principle just means that to add new behavior to your system you should create a new implementing class rather than change old ones. Using an abstract class for that is fine.

The one thing that does violate encapsulation (which is a different principle) is the package-accessible dependency setter. You can fix that issue by changing it to be a protected setter. Then extending classes can set their own, but outside callers cannot change the states of your objects.

```
protected final void setSysProp(ClassThatSetEnvironmentProperty sysProp) {
    this.sysProp = sysProp;
}
```

Comment: I agree. Thank you

Comment: Protected is *less* restrictive than package private (default).

Comment: @OleV.V. They are differently restrictive. Protected ensures that all extending classes have access to it. For shared APIs, that is a critical requirement.

Comment: @SilasReinagel, either you or I have not completely understood [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).